# JavaScript: How to call functions from events

Tags: javascript, function, events, anonymous-function

I'm starting to learn JavaScript and I would know how to call a function from an event. The only way I know is with anonymous functions (see my code) and I don't know how to call it in a simpler way. Thanks in advance!

```
    function example (){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function (){
            example2 ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign it by name:

```
function example (){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = example2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kamituel, I was trying it always with the () after its name and didn't work. I'm a total beginner as you can see :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way - if you found my solution correct, you can mark it as an accepted answer - this way other people who see this question in the future will know it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick=example2;
```